# Vue3 route.query empty

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Trying to pass route query to `axios` request, but it is empty..
`route.query` returns empty in mounted. `route.query`returns  `{"filter[city]": "Vilnius" }` in axios `then`
`nextTick` doesn't solve issue. Any tips?

```js
import { ref, onMounted, nextTick } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default {
    setup() {
        const router = useRouter();
        const route = useRoute();

        onMounted(() => {
            console.log(route.query);  // log is {}
            fetchApartments();
        });
    
        function fetchApartments() {
            console.log(route.query); // log is {}
        
            axios.get('/api/apartments').then(response => {
                console.log(route.query); // log is { "filter[city]": "Vilnius" }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Route navigation is asynchronous. You need to wait for `router.isReady` for queries to be available

```js
import {useRouter, useRoute} from 'vue-router';

export default {
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const route = useRoute();
    
    onMounted(async () => {
      await router.isReady();
      console.log(route.query);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code like this:

```
...
import { computed } from 'vue'
...
```

and inside setup()

```
const route = useRoute();
const query = computed(() => route.query)
```

The missing part here is computed property.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: It works, query is ref. Use query.value to get object of params.